# How do I do 6-key Braille input?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, macos

Does Mac OS X have a facility for 6 key (Perkins) Braille typing? That is using <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> & <kbd>L</kbd> to type in the various Braille cells (mapping respectively to <kbd>⠁</kbd>, <kbd>⠂</kbd>, <kbd>⠄</kbd>, <kbd>⠈</kbd>, <kbd>⠐</kbd>& <kbd>⠠</kbd>) on the keyboard. I don't want to have to use the character palette as that would really slow me down. If OS X doesn't have it out of the box, what 3rd party tools are good?

An answer for 8-key input is also acceptable.

Comment: This blog post seems to assert that you can use ControllerMate and a custom script to get the basics to work http://janrobertmenzel.de/2008/03/keyboard-braille/

Answer (score 2):

Just recently out I think, Braille Writer for OS X:

http://ethervision.net/blog/braille-writer-mac-apple

If you have an iOS device, you there is Braille Pad.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/braille-pad-pro/id544696675?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/braille-pad-student/id551373276?mt=8